# How do I get smart suggestions for React in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

It worked well a few days ago and suddenly stopped showing suggestions. Do I have to install any plugins?

Comment: Do you mean it stopped showing the API signatures?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by API signatures. But here's my issue: usually when I type 'React.' VS would show all the functions as suggestions. Now it's not showing it...

Comment: That's the same thing. Check [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript) to read more about how vscode auto-acquires the type signatures. There may be some environmental issues preventing it from doing that. You can try specifying the type acquisitions manually.

Comment: When such sudden things happen without any obvious changes from outside - you probably want to reinstall VSCode. And if it does not help - verify is the problem is specific to your machine or can be reproduced with the same project on other computers.

Comment: This worked for me, you just have to install the types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717736/4307638

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can install this extensions for your vscode just copy this code with press `ctrl+p` react native tools

```
ext install vscode-react-native
```

or you can try to search from extension page on vscode with **React Native Tools** as a keyword

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Sublime Babel plugin (`ext install sublime-babel-vscode`) and VS Code started to show me suggestions again... I think there seems to be a conflict between the editor and the plugin.