# VSCode autocomplete extension for React Native?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I'm using VSCode with my React Native project and want to get the same autocomplete extension used in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kXF-IrJ_SI&ab_channel=EuanMorgan) for the 5s clip at 1:08:12, where it shows you what properties there are of a given import etc. I installed TabNine, but it doesn't make any suggestions when I type the name of an import, or anything else.

Comment: It's been a long time since the question was asked. But I want the same thing. Did you find it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native with TypeScript and you will get really powerful autocompletion support, I believe you can do the same in JavaScript projects if you installed `@types/react-native` like that
`npm i -D @types/react-native`